# C# Winforms autoupdate check

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-installer

I am trying to make autoupdate check and upgrade procedure (now from location on shared drive, in future maybe from server).

I have created "Visual Studio Installer" project that creates setup and it is possible to install the app. Also I have created another binary that searches for updates - if there are updates and user wants it, it runs the setup and app ends - if no updates, it runs main program. I have selected 2 binaries system in order to have possibility to run app without updates checking.

But If I confirm the update I am getting "Another version of this product is already installed. error code..." dialog.

I am not sure if my approach is right, probably not. But I found only commerce solutions and ClickOnce which seems to be for updating from network.

Thank you in advices for your answers.

Comment: Have you changed from x32 to x64 or vice versa since original install? Or deploying in Debug when previously in Release? I would uninstall the existing install, install from new exe, then make small change, ensure version number increased and publish again. The check for updates to see if that sorts it

Comment: @JonRoberts The app and the setup are working fine independently. The mentioned problem occurs when I try to start the setup from the app.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for something that allow you to have folder in your disk or a shared drive that can be used as local server to help you make updates without using internet connection , I introduce you to Squirrel.Windows its an open source installation and update framework for Windows desktop apps.

Here is link for [Getting Started With Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/develop/docs/getting-started/0-overview.md).
And here is a [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8Qu4qMJyh4) by Tim Corey where he explain Squirrel practically with demo windows forms  project.

Happy Codding...